# If time2 is greater than 9 hours to time 1 then true

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am writing a code for VB.NET for time in and out. My problem is when `time2` is greater than 9 hours to `time1` then I want true statement in this condition.

```
tat.Text = myreader.Item("Status").ToString
abs = myreader.Item("Time_In").ToString
abs1 = myreader.Item("Time_In").ToString
EndTime = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
StartTime = TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
'  Main.oras.Text = StartTime

gtg2 = abs
gtg3 = gtg2.AddHours(9)
gtg4 = abs1


If gtg3 > gtg4 Then
   Label32.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

Comment: What are your data types on the database? Have a look at a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2 for calculating time differences.

Comment: You can use `If time2 - time1 > TimeSpan.FromHours(9) Then` whether `time2` and `time1` are type `DateTime` or `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello , using VB.net , what i'm trying to do is when the inputted time is greater than 9 hours the true statement will say its over time.

Comment: If time1 <= time1.AddHours(9) Then

                Label32.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim dt1 = #1/4/2019 8:00#
Dim dt2 = #1/4/2019 20:00#
If dt2 - dt1 > TimeSpan.FromHours(9) Then
    MsgBox("Time is more than 9 hours")
Else
    MsgBox("Time is less than 9 hours")
End If
```

Comment: I was posting a comment using the same code while you posted this.  It's worth noting that the same `If` statement would work for `TimeSpan` values as well as for `DateTime` values.

Comment: Hello , using VB.net , what i'm trying to do is when the inputted time is greater than 9 hours the true statement will say its over time.

Comment: @HisLombres I gave you the answer. Adapt it to your code.

Comment: Thank  you so much! its already working now :)

Comment: @HisLombres You're welcome! 

Answer (score 0):

I've created this function if the endtime is more than 9 hours from starttime:

```
Private Function GreaterThan9Hours(ByVal StartTime As DateTime, ByVal EndTime As DateTime) As Boolean
    If EndTime - StartTime > TimeSpan.FromHours(9) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is very nice! this is worked from me! thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You're welcome His!

Comment: The code inside the `Private Function ... End Function` lines can be even simpler. `Return (EndTime - StartTime) > TimeSpan.FromHours(9)`. No need for  any extra steps.